# On OSX a <select> element always has first option checked by default

Tags: html, macos

I want to have a `<select>` element with no items selected/checked. On Windows this is easy, you just don't specify a `selected` attribute. On OSX, it automatically puts a checkmark on the first item even if there is no `selected` attribute. Is it possible on OSX to have a select element with no items selected by default? Even if the first item is blank, it still puts a checkmark on it.

```html
<select>
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
  <option>Third</option>
  <option>Fourth</option>
  <option>Fifth</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov It's actually not the same issue (I don't want the checkmark to appear on the first item) but the accepted answer of adding a `disabled` attribute to the first item is actually an acceptable solution for me. It still has the checkmark on the first item, but it's grey and not selectable. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, it is, but was thinking that accepted answer will be correct in this case too, that's why I've added reference to this question.